# Show loading icon during the javascript execution in asp .net page

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I need to show loading icon when the page loads or clicking the link in the page which calls a javascript. Code is fully written in javascript for any operation in asp .net
Any suggestion would be helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't use something like

```
  <img src="Icon.png">
```

because you're not sure if the image will be fetched before the page. Especially if they refresh the page, it won't be likely.

For a static image, Probably the best way to do it is with a data url (search in Google and you can find someone to encode any image into a data url).

Or you can use some animated css, which is becoming more popular. Search for "css loader spinners" on Google and you'll find a number of examples.